# Login page being hit 3 times

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I am baffled by this.  I have a master page on top of a few pages, one of them is a login page.  Here is a sample of web.config

```
        <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
        </authentication>

    ...

      <location path="~/Account/Login.aspx">
        <system.web>
          <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
          </authorization>
        </system.web>
      </location>
  <location path="Default.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

From Default.aspx, I access About.aspx which requires a login.  The About.aspx never gets hit, instead Login.aspx gets hit, then Site.master, then login again, then site.master again, and finally login.aspx, and master.aspx.  Three times! ... Login-> Master are being hit 3 times! ... now... if I change the line of code from Web.config from

```
 <location path="~/Account/Login.aspx">
```

to

```
 <location path="Account">
```

Login->Master only get hit once.  There is nothing else besides login.aspx/cs/designer in the Account folder. Why is this happening?  I would like to control pages in the Account folder when I add more and not just lift the access to them all, but even

```
 <location path="Account/Login.aspx">
```

(removed "~/") didn't do anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is your `Site.master` file located?

Comment: How do you determine when a page is "hit"?

Comment: Site.master is located in the root directory.  I am determining the page hit count by putting in page breaks into master page and login page Page_Load method, and every other page for that matter to make sure it's not being sent there by other means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should allow all access to your `MasterPage` similar to how you allow anyone access to your Login page.

It will not be served up on it's own and doesn't need to be secured since the page that uses it should be locked down.  Normally I have the root unsecured which has the login pages, master pages, about etc.  I then have a secured area that has pages that use the master page from the root.

Comment: That's a good idea.  That didn't solve the problem but I agree with you and will give you a point for that.  After all, I am removing access from Images, Scripts, and Styles folder as it is anyway.

Comment: @Lukas so your login and master page is all in your root and the web.config is allowing anon access to those pages?  If so there should be nothing causing the login page to be hit... do you have user controls or something of the sort in secured directories?  The behaviour your describing is definately odd.

Comment: At the moment yes.  Master page, web.config, default.aspx, etc, are in the root directory; every page other than Login.aspx is (other than some controls, custom providers, etc).  The above have anon access, yes. About.aspx is a blank page, I wanted to make sure that wasn't the cause and it wasn't.  This is perplexing to say the least.

Comment: I should add, if I move Login.aspx to the root directory, problem goes away.

Comment: @Lukas Login page should be in root... whe whole root can be setup up to allow anyone access.  Then have a web.config in a secured dir that locks everything down.  Then you have a clear seperation and not having to tweek access in a web.config.

Comment: Yeah I think that's exactly what I'll have to do.  I'd like to know why it's happening, but if correct topology practice solves it, then so be it.  Giving you checkmark for this since re-arranging the order will fix the issue technically.